# String argument after parameter pack

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

I want to write a function `write` that can take multiple arguments of any type, and print them to `stdout`.
But I also want to pass in a delimiter as the last argument as well.

```cpp
template <typename... T>
void write(T &&...args, string delimiter) { // compilation error
    ((cout << args << delimiter),...);
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
write(1, ""); // single element with empty delimeter
write(1, "one", " "); // space as delimeter
write(1, "one", ","); // comma as delimeter
```

Right now, automatic type deduction fails since C++ expects parameter packs to be the last argument.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `write("a","b","c")`? It can be parsed either way, with "c" either being deduced as the delimiter, or as the last in a three-parameter pack. Parameter packs only work when they are the ***last*** function parameter.

Comment: Have `write(T&& ...args)` that has `","` delimiter hard-coded, and `write_using_delim(string delimiter, T&& ..args)` that the caller provides a delimiter as the first argument.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik good point, lets say I am fine with removing the default value. So last argument will always be string and it will be delimeter, how to achieve even that?

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate that you want the last parameter to always be a string delimiter.

Comment: @cigien question has been edited

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `write("a", "b", "c")` is exactly as ambiguous when you have `write(T... args, std::string foo)` as when you have `write(std::string foo, T... args)`. Whatever the order is, you first get the arguments that must not be a part of the pack (`foo`) and then the remainings ones become a part of the pack. I honestly don't know why pack must be the last argument, probably the commitees had some better argument for that.

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice technique in this [blog article](https://www.bfilipek.com/2020/09/variadic-pack-first.html) which you can use.

Modify `write` to only accept a parameter pack

```
template <typename... Ts>
void write(Ts && ...args) 
{ 
    write_indirect(std::forward_as_tuple(args...),
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args) - 1>{});
}
```

Now `write_indirect` simply takes the parameter pack as a tuple, along with the indices of the arguments as template parameters. Then it extracts the last parameter using `get`, and passes that as the first parameter to `write_impl`. The remaining parameters are unpacked from the tuple, and passed as the second argument

```
template<typename... Ts, size_t... Is>
void write_indirect(std::tuple<Ts...> args, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    auto constexpr Last = sizeof...(Ts) - 1;
    write_impl(std::get<Last>(args), std::get<Is>(args)...);
}
```

Now `write_impl` is just your original `write` function but it takes the delimiter as the first argument

```
template <typename... Ts>
void write_impl(std::string delimiter, Ts && ...args) 
{   
    ((std::cout << args << delimiter),...);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bKq456Pab)

Comment: I mean this does work, but its too much work. C++ should have something better, I think named parameters could enable a much easier implementation.